# How to find all frozensets that are subsets of another frozenset in a set of frozensets?

Tags: python, set, tuples

I am having trouble searching for the solution (if previously asked) to this problem because it's kind of hard to explain in a search.

I have a set of frozensets, like:

```
my_set = {
    frozenset({1, 2, 3}),
    frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4}),
    frozenset({1, 2, 3, 5}),
    frozenset({1, 3, 5}),
    frozenset({1, 2})
}
```

I want all the frozensets that are subsets of any other frozenset in the set, with a function `get_subsets` whose output is like:

```
subsets = get_subsets(my_set)
subsets == {
    frozenset({1, 2, 3}),
    frozenset({1, 3, 5}),
    frozenset({1, 2})
}
```

would return True. How can I get this? I previously had a set of tuples but revised to frozensets, as I was using touples before because they are hashable. I also asked to do it without iterating over the set because in my case I have hundreds of thousands of items in my set; now I revise to:

What's the fastest way to do this (now embracing iteration)?

Comment: why does `(1,)` not solve your problem?

Comment: Have you tried to write anything or you just prefer the code from someone else?

Comment: You obviously know how to use sets, since you built one. And you know that what you're trying to do is a set operation, so… (If you see where I'm going here and just want to know how you may a set of sets, that's a bit tricky—you have to actually make a set of `frozenset`s instead.)

Comment: Also, there really is no way to do this without iterating over the set. There's no way to find "all X such that Y" without looking at all X.

Comment: (Unless the values are sorted in a relevant way, of course… but then sorting them requires iterating them.)

Comment: @StephenRauch (1,) was not a part of my set to begin with; I want the function to return only elements of my input set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with itertools , Here is my approach:

```
import itertools
my_set = {
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 2, 3, 4),
    (1, 2, 3, 5),
    (1, 3, 5),
    (1,2)
}
```

With itertools.product :

```
print(set([ii[0] for ii in itertools.product(my_set,repeat=2) if ii[0]!=ii[1] and set(ii[0]).issubset(set(ii[1]))]))
```

output:

```
{(1, 3, 5), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3)}
```

With itertools.combination :

```
print(list(filter(None,set([i[0] if set(i[0]).issubset(i[1]) else i[1] if set(i[1]).issubset(set(i[0])) else None for i in itertools.combinations(my_set,r=2)]))))
```

output:

```
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, it is impossible. You can't do the comparisons that are necessary without iteration. With that in mind I have some workable code which does what you want:

```
def get_subsets(SET):
my_List = [] #a list to hold the sets   
L = [] #another list for later
for Set in SET:
    New = set(Set)
    my_List.append(New)

for i in range(len(my_List)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(my_List)):

        if i+2 == len(my_List): #this is so the last element doesn't get double counted
            break

        if my_List[i].issubset(my_List[j]):
            L.append(tuple(my_List[i]))
        if my_List[i].issuperset(my_List[j]):
            L.append(tuple(my_List[j]))


return set(L)
```

Testing this on your set gives the desired results. This is by no means the best code which could be written to get the job done, but it does what you want it to.